# Ruby getting "can't modify frozen string" error when trying to use Rudyscript2exe

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've got a ruby script on this Mac, that I want to distribute to Windows users.  I'm trying to use the gem Rubyscript2exe to make an executable, but when I run the following command:

```
$ rubyscript2exe jabberbot.rb
```

I get the folowing error:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rubyscript2exe-0.5.3/bin/rubyscript2exe:5:in `replace': can't modify frozen string (TypeError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rubyscript2exe-0.5.3/bin/rubyscript2exe:5
from /usr/bin/rubyscript2exe:19:in `load'
from /usr/bin/rubyscript2exe:19
```

/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rubyscript2exe-0.5.3/bin/rubyscript2exe is

```
gemdir  = File.expand_path("..", File.dirname(__FILE__))
realstuff   = File.expand_path("realstuff.rb", gemdir)
isapplication   = File.basename(File.dirname(__FILE__)) == "bin"

$0.replace(realstuff)   if isapplication

load(realstuff)
```

Line 19 of /usr/bin/rubyscript2exe is

```
load Gem.bin_path('rubyscript2exe', 'rubyscript2exe', version)
```

**New issue:**

After replacing the code as answered I am now getting this error:

```
/private/tmp/tar2rubyscript.d.4970.1/rubyscript2exe/rubyscript2exe.rb:37:in `expand_path': can't convert nil into String (TypeError)
from /private/tmp/tar2rubyscript.d.4970.1/rubyscript2exe/rubyscript2exe.rb:37:in `appdir'
from /private/tmp/tar2rubyscript.d.4970.1/rubyscript2exe/rubyscript2exe.rb:96
from /private/tmp/tar2rubyscript.d.4970.1/rubyscript2exe/init.rb:2:in `load'
from /private/tmp/tar2rubyscript.d.4970.1/rubyscript2exe/init.rb:2
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rubyscript2exe-0.5.3/realstuff.rb:632:in `load'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rubyscript2exe-0.5.3/realstuff.rb:632
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rubyscript2exe-0.5.3/realstuff.rb:577:in `newlocation'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rubyscript2exe-0.5.3/realstuff.rb:505:in `newlocation'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rubyscript2exe-0.5.3/realstuff.rb:472:in `newlocation'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rubyscript2exe-0.5.3/realstuff.rb:505:in `newlocation'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rubyscript2exe-0.5.3/realstuff.rb:577:in `newlocation'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rubyscript2exe-0.5.3/realstuff.rb:619
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rubyscript2exe-0.5.3/bin/rubyscript2exe:11:in `load'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rubyscript2exe-0.5.3/bin/rubyscript2exe:11
from /usr/bin/rubyscript2exe:19:in `load'
from /usr/bin/rubyscript2exe:19
```

Comment: Try to open the file `rubyscript2exe' under the path as given in the message, and give us what the lines around line 5 and line 19 look like.

Comment: Should I just open a new question for the new issue?

Comment: It is better if you continue here, unless you strongly want to. By the way, what version of rubyscript2exe are you using?

Comment: I 've got the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is due to a specification change made in ruby 1.8.7 and ruby1.9. `$0` refers to the program name, but it became frozen. Are you using the newest version of `rubyscript2exe`? If not, try the newest version. If the problem is still there, then, as suggested by [rubyscript2exe](https://github.com/cowlibob/rubyscript2exe), change the line:

```
$0.replace(realstuff)   if isapplication
```

to these:

```
# $0.replace(realstuff)   if isapplication   # original
$__0 = realstuff   if isapplication          # added
alias $__0 $0                                # added
alias $0 $_0                                 # added
```

Answer (score 0):

This link may help: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3173966

You can use ocra: http://ocra.rubyforge.org/

This way:

```
gem install ocra
ocra --console myapp.rb
```

Comment: OCRA is not available for Linux